# Prove that this process is a Markov Chain process and display your transition matrix

Tags: proof-writing, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, transition-matrix

I am trying to solve this exercise:

*At time $0$, a box contains one white ball and one black ball. At each time `n = 1,2,3,4...`, one ball is randomly choosen. After that, the ball is re-inserted on the box and a new ball with the same color is inserted in the box. Hece, at `n`, the box is going to have `(n+2)` balls. Define `B_n` as the number of black balls chosen untill time `n`. Show that this process is a Markov Chain and present the transition matrix.*

I have a partial solution but I think my proof is wrong. I know the definition of a markov chain and I have read similar questions like this one on Stack Exchange. However, I was not able to make a decent proof.

That'st my try on the transition matrix for the problem above (probably wrong):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 &0 &0 &\cdots \\
0& 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 &0 &0 &\cdots \\
0 & 0 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/4 &1/4 &\cdots \\
\vdots & &&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: the transition matrix depends explicitly on $n$, since the number of white balls is not part of the state. Noticing that will also help you prove the Markov property.

Comment: I still can't figure out how to get the transition matrix. Where I am stuck is, that going from state, let's say, '1 black ball' to '2 black balls', we don't know how many white balls there are in the urn. Therefore, we won't know the probability in choosing that one black ball among how many white balls. How can you incorporate the $n$ in $B_n$? Then it would tell us how many white balls there are.

Comment: @soobster The transition probability matrix for $B_n$ can depend explicitly on $n$. In other words $P(B_{n+1} \in A \mid B_n=x)$ can depend on both $x$ and $n$. This happens here: in particular $P_n(i,i+1)=\frac{i}{n+1}$ (for a suitable range of $i$, I guess $1 \leq i \leq n$) since there are $n+1$ balls in the urn in total *before* the draw that is performed at time $n$.